# list questions: questions that group very similar questions

Tags: feature-request, questions

**Some background..**

I noticed that the amount of questions of a very specific issue is not only big, but keeps getting bigger. Given that some of there are very similar, finding the right question (critical not to ask a duplicate) takes most of my time. I was wondering if some grouping or hierarchy could help to accelerate that process?

I have seen in meta the discussions of tag hierarchies :) , so here I'm asking about something similar.

**How about list questions?** *[community wiki?]*

How about questions that are *a list* or *a directory* of other questions, created by users when seemed fit? How? Let's say there is a Java Exception *OverDoseException*, then the entry would look like:

> OverDoseException - title [just an example]
>
> Thrown by Smoker Class, since Java 51.1...
>
> Users have found this in Android this exception  when processing images, the reason is that since API 5...
>
> - [question 1]
> - [question 2]
>
> ...
>
> In multithreading this was the root cause for other exceptions...
>
> - [question]
> - [question2] ...

This kind of grouping is not evident in the search results if you lookup by the exception name simply because any item in one category may have the keywords of

**Implementing the list question**

I guess it would be a community wiki and anyone would then help populate the list.  I think in practice there's NO WAY ALL questions will be listed and no one wants that, instead the ones that tend to have too many similar.

In fact the list questions will be created only if it feels they're needed

In terms of actual feature request, a distinction (a filter for instance) in the search results would help so we can browse all questions normally, but allow searching by lists if we're searching a subject that has many related posts. maybe just a tag would be enough?

But definitely users should have access to modify it because the OP of a question is a good candidate to add it to a list

**To consider**

- They can be ignored by the reader at his will
- It can help us readers when tags are not enough
- NOT JUST THIS EXAMPLE, not just exceptions may be a list question, there may be *softer* lists like 'exemplary efficiency in socket handling'  which would list questions that feature exceptional code; but their keywords and tags won't have them grouped in a search result
- It can create a flow of unwanted questions
- answers to list questions have no meaning

Comment: Related: http://meta.stackexchange.com/questions/66362/why-not-group-related-questions-in-to-some-sort-of-guide-or-have-a-hierarchy-to

Comment: Would this in some way be served by a tag-wiki being maintained, much as the C++ tag wiki is?

Comment: This should be done through Tag Wikis, see here http://meta.stackexchange.com/a/160127/200868

Comment: @jcolebrand I was not aware of those tag wiki, but it surely is something useful for this. The only drawback (room for improvement) that I see is that as a reader you search by keywords maybe bypassing the tags.  Shouldn't you post this as an answer? maybe that's the way the community wants it?

Comment: If anything, this should be closed as a duplicate of that as the result is the same answer. Alternately I could post his answer as mine here. But that would doubly reinforce that this should just be closed as a dupe. @AnnaLear do you agree?

Comment: Oh and as for what should you do to help make this a more popular idea so that more people know about it? Engage those you come across who seem to be looking for lists to encourage them to observe and contribute on the same concept, so that they too are looking at tag wikis the same as you are. And when you find one that could be made better, suggest an edit.