# Highlighting the best content of the year

Tags: discussion

It would be very interesting to see some of the best, most debated, most discussed, most useful, most creative or even plain humorous posts of the year highlighted in or at one place. This could be done in maybe a blog post, or maybe as a meta post.

Obviously, deciding the "best" posts is rather subjective especially since votes are not the only way to judge how a post affected the community and was responded to. So, i suggest that, if this were to be done, then the "best" posts be selected by the moderators and staff at their discretion.

---

and the award goes to **The C, C++ and PHP Tag Wikis**

Comment: Personally, one of my favorite posts on SO was [the interviewer that told the Java developer you can instantiate an abstract class](http://stackoverflow.com/questions/13670991/interview-can-we-instantiate-abstract-class/13671003#13671003).

Classic.

Answer (score 14, accepted):

### The [C](https://stackoverflow.com/tags/c/info), [C++](https://stackoverflow.com/tags/c++/info) and [PHP](https://stackoverflow.com/tags/php/info) Tag Wikis

These are shining examples of how to anchor your sub-community with a Tag Wiki that works.  Notably:

1. They explain what the tag is about, and contain background information useful to beginners.  They are a road map, of sorts.
2. They all contain commonly-asked questions by beginners, and links to canonical posts that fully answer these questions.  That way, when they get the 50th `i++ + ++i` question, they can simply close it as a duplicate of the canonical post.

These communities get away with some things that the general community can not, because they have *taken ownership of their community*.  For example, the mother of all Not Constructive questions, [The Definitive C++ Book Guide and List](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/388242/the-definitive-c-book-guide-and-list) is neither closed nor locked.  Why?  Because the C++ community aggressively curates and maintains this list.

Any one of these three Tag Wikis (and I'm sure there are more that I've left out here) are suitable examples from which to draw inspiration for creating other tag wikis, and some tags really need this (Android comes to mind).

Comment: Since you praise them you should probably link to them for the ignorant (like me) to revel in their beauty: [C](http://stackoverflow.com/tags/c/info), [C++](http://stackoverflow.com/tags/c%2b%2b/info), [PHP](http://stackoverflow.com/tags/php/info).

Comment: The [scala tag wiki](http://stackoverflow.com/tags/scala/info) is also quite good.